# Filtrar resultados de últimas 24 horas en query de SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda con la siguiente query:

```
SELECT [Columna1], count(*)
FROM [Tabla1]
WHERE [Columna_Tiempo]
GROUP BY [Columna]
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer con esta consulta es hacer el conteo agrupado de los valores de la `Columna1`, pero quisiera que solo me muestre los registros de las últimas 24 horas.

Yo tengo una `Columna_Tiempo` en formato `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` pero no se que condición poner en `WHERE` para que me filtre los resultados.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

¡Un saludo a todos!

Comment: para tu pregunta contarías 24hrs desde la hora de la consulta o te referirías a 24hrs como el día de la ejecución, por ejemplo ejecuto la consulta a las 9:00 AM del 12 de mayo, el rango seria desde las 9:00 AM del 12 de mayo hasta 9:00 AM del 11 de mayo, o seria desde las 9:00 AM del 12 de mayo hasta 00:00 AM del 12 de mayo.

Comment: Hola Roberto. La verdad me interesan las dos alternativas que mencionas en tu comentario.  Por un lado saber como  filtrar los resultados 24hs desde hecha la consulta, y también tener un registro que vaya digamos desde las 9:00 AM de hoy hasta el día anterior. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Cambié la etiqueta _mssql_ (que según la Wiki de etiqueta es para el cliente de node.js) por _sql-server_ que es para el motor de base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo has buscado sobre intervalos?....
Aquí te dejo un poco de código:

```
SELECT [COLUMNA1] 
FROM [TABLA1]
WHERE [Columna_Tiempo] >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Hola Wilson. Probé con esta consulta y obtuve la siguiente respuesta: mssql: 'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Que motor de base de datos estas usando?

Comment: @Marcos corregido el tag. Mil disculpas.

Comment: Hola Wilson, estoy utilizando Grafana para hacer las consultas conectado con mi base de datos.

Comment: la última edición parece funcionar. Esto muestra los resultados hasta 24hs antes de hecha la consulta, correcto?